# Is it possible to link a table cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, google-maps, uitableview

I wonder if it is possible to link a table cell in a tableview.
I have a tableview with two sections. The first section hold some address data in six cells and the second section has only one cell and this should call the google maps app when clicked. Is something like this possible and how does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `didSelectRowForIndexPath` filter on `indexPath.section` and `indexPath.row`.  `indexPath.section` should be 1 (=second section) and `indexpath.row` should be 0 (=first row). 
If both match you trigger the required action.

Answer (score 0):

@crazer yes it is possible to link a custom table cell in your `UITableView`.....if i understant your problem well u need to print different data in two setions through custom table cell......that u will do through the conditions .......but u have to subclass UITableViewCell. For further information please follow the link (Table View Cells - Subclassing UITableViewCell).....http://www.bogotobogo.com/XcodeSDK-Chapter7B.html

Hope u got my point!! Good Luck

Comment: Hi Sudhanshu, I already customized my table cells. What I want to do is call the maps app when the cell is touched.

Comment: @crazer Hi k as u had customized your tablecell as u r saying.....now as u had put your custom cells on different rows of your table view....open URL of google map inside didSelectRowAtIndexPath for that particular index.